# Events being fired after end of the window when processing unbounded stream of data

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, stream-processing, windowing

**Given**: unbounded stream of data with some duplicate events that are located close to each (in terms of time); duplicate events have the same event timestamp and same unique id

**Goal**: remove duplicates from the stream

I planned to apply a fixed-size window, then group given events by a unique key and perform early fire. So I have something like the following:

```
(
    element
    | "Add timestamp to event" >> ParDo(AddTimestampCustomFn())    # simply return TimistampedValue
    | "Select unique key" >> Map(lambda elem: (elem.id, elem))
    | "Apply window" >> WindowInto(
        FixedWindows(50),
        trigger=AfterCount(1),
        accumulation_mod=AccumulationMode.DISCARDING,
        allowed_lateness=0,
    )
    | "Group events by id" >> GroupByKey()
    | "Print results" >> ParDo(CustomPrintFn())    # simply print the first element from the grouped elements along with timestamp
)
```

Everything seems to be working as expected, but I realized that even after some time has passed it's still possible to process an event that belongs to the time window which supposedly should have already been passed.

Let's say we have the following events with the corresponding timestamps: `[('a', 0), ('a', 1), ('a', 40), ('b', 20), ('c', 90), ('d', '140'), ('f', 1)]`. I would expect my output to be something like: `[('a', 49), ('b', 49), ('c': 99), ('d', 149)]`. However, in addition to the above output I also get `f` event. So the actual output is `[('a', 49), ('b', 49), ('c': 99), ('d', 149), ('f', 49)]`. It's worth noting that the timestamp of the grouped events is equal to the last time of the time window. I don't quite understand why I get `f` event. The window is fixed, its length is 50 seconds and `allowed_lateness` set to 0. I would also assume that the watermark should have already passed. Therefore, I can't really understand why event `f` is still there?

I also tried executing code with no group by statements. However, it seems to produce similar results. Let's we have the following data as our input: `[('a', 1), ('b', 90), ('c', 140), ('f', 1)]`. Then the result still includes event `f`: `[('a', 49), ('b', 99), ('c', 149), ('f', 49)]`. Here is the simplified code:

```
(
    element
    | "Add timestamp to event" >> ParDo(AddTimestampCustomFn())
    | "Apply window" >> WindowInto(FixedWindows(50))
    | "Print results" >> ParDo(CustomPrintFn())
)
```

I feel like my understanding of the fixed-window is wrong but I cannot get why.

Answer (score 1):

The watermark behavior depends on the source; it may not be advancing the way you think, so all of the data here is probably on-time and not dropped.

In particular, if you are using Create, the watermark starts at negative infinity, all elements are injected into the pipeline, then the watermark advances to positive infinity.  This ensures that none of the data is late, regardless of the order you gave to Create.

If you want to explicitly control both element injection and the watermark for testing purposes, you can use [TestStream](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.22.0/apache_beam.testing.test_stream.html).

Comment: I see, I was actually using `TestStream` to advance my watermark in unit tests but it still doesn't produce the expected result. Let's say I have the following messages: `message = [('a', 1), ('b', 90), ('c', 140), ('f', 1)]`. Then I create test stream: `test_stream = TestStream.advance_watermark(1).add_elements(messages[:3]).advance_watermark(1000).add_elements(messages[3:])`
After that I execute my pipeline I specified in the question. However, it still receives event `f` for some reason which lives in window [0, 50).

Comment: Is that with the simplified code or the original? The grouping and late data dropping occurs in the first GroupByKey after the Window transform, not immediately.

Comment: This is a simplified version of the code without GroupByKey clause

Comment: Yeah, without the GBK, this is expected behavior, since late data dropping happens in the GBK.  If this still happens with the GBK, then something else is going on.